# error "Target class [Wazawaza2Middleware] does not exist."

Tags: laravel

I want to use middleware in laravel but show that.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mWuw6.png)

I think my code is right.

Wazawaza2Middleware.php

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

use Closure;

class Wazawaza2Middleware
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if(Auth::check()){
            return $next($request);
        }else{
            return view('auth.login');
        }
    }
}
```

web.php

```
use App\Http\Middleware\Wazawaza2Middleware;

Route::get('topde', 'ReviewController@top')->middleware('Wazawaza2Middleware::class');
```

Kernel.php

```
    protected $routeMiddleware = [
      .
      .
      .
    'wazawaza2' =>
        \App\Http\Middleware\Wazawaza2Middleware::class,
    ];
```

Comment: Please edit your question to provide more details, such as where your error is occurring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an error in your web.php, should be:

```
use App\Http\Middleware\Wazawaza2Middleware;

Route::get('topde', 'ReviewController@top')->middleware(Wazawaza2Middleware::class);
```

OR (since you are aliasing it)

```
Route::get('topde', 'ReviewController@top')->middleware('wazawaza2');
```